# Generic controller class with inheritance .NET

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, asp.net-web-api

I am making a custom controller class, from which all my other controller classes will inherit in .Net Framework 4.8, Web API

```cs
public class BaseApiController<T> where T: class, ApiController
{
    protected T service;

    public BaseApiController(T service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }
}
```

This gives a compile-time error

> Error CS0450  'ApiController': cannot specify both a constraint class
>   and the 'class' or 'struct' constraint

I know I am missing small detail with the right syntax.
`T` is a service, which is individual for every controller and I want to make sure it is always a reference type. I also want to inherit from the main `ApiController` class.

If I do it like this, there are no errors (This works for me):

```cs
public class BaseApiController<T> : ApiController
{
    protected T service;

    public BaseApiController(T service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }
}
```

But I want the additional `T` logic for reference type.

I want to use it like this, e.g:
Note: This how I use it and it works.

```cs
[Authorize]
[RoutePrefix("api/[controller]")]
public class MyOtherController : BaseApiController<IMyOtherService>
{
    public MyOtherController(IMyOtherService myOtherService) : base(myOtherService)
    {

    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult DoSomething(Model requestModel)
    {
        var result = this.service.SetPaymentStatusUK(model: requestModel);
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

I just want to know how to add the `T` check for reference type in the `BaseApiController` class.

Comment: You added ApiControler as a Generic Constraint, rather then the class to inherit/Interface to implement. Basically you put that class in the wrong spot.

Comment: Since no `struct` could inherit from `ApiController`, what do you think `class` is adding for you here?

Comment: The proper syntax is to inherit first, then constrain. This is from the examples `class SpecialNodeItem<T> : NodeItem<T> where T : System.IComparable<T>, new() { }` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-classes

Comment: Thanks, accepted as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question right, the issue is that you applied `ApiControler` as a Constraint to T. When you wanted to apply it as a Ancestor of `BaseApiController<T>`.

As a constraint `ApiControler` it is not valid, because you already applied the `class` constraint. `class` include all classes, including ApiControler and every other class that has yet to be written. It is a less restrictive constraint the ApiControler. You only use a specific type or inferface as constraint, if you want all possible T's the absolutely positively have that inheritance/Interface Implementation.

According to the [Syntax examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-classes), you first inherit, then you constrain. So:

```
public class BaseApiController<T> : ApiController where T: class
{
  //all the code
}
```

Might be the droid you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed. CHeers